# Representation of symmetry operators in second quantuzation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, topological-insulators

*Hamiltonian invariant under a symmetry-* The action of a group $G$ on the set of Bloch momentum is given by a linear representation $T_g: k \to T_g k \equiv k_g $. Now say that a fermionic Bloch Hamiltonian is invariant under the action of such Group. In second quantization this means

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\mathcal U_g \mathcal H \mathcal U_g^{-1} = \mathcal H,
\end{equation}
Here, $\mathcal U_g$ represents the group action of $G$ on the hilbert space in second quantization, as
\begin{align}
\tag{2}
\label{2}
\mathcal U_g c_{k\alpha} \mathcal U_g^{-1} = c_{k_g\alpha}\\
\tag{3}
\label{3}
\mathcal U_g c^\dagger_{k\alpha} \mathcal U_g^{-1} = c^\dagger_{k_g\alpha}
\end{align}
The Hamiltonian is a non-interacting fermionic Hamiltonian, such as
\begin{equation}
\tag{4}\label{4}
\mathcal H = \sum_{k \alpha \beta} c^\dagger_{k \alpha} H(k)_{\alpha \beta} c_{k \beta}
\end{equation}
Where, $\alpha, \beta$ are internal quantum numbers and $H(k)$ is the matrix valued Hamiltonian (also known as first quantized Hamiltonian) written in the basis $c^\dagger_{k\alpha}\left|0\right>$. Due of the symmetry \eqref{1} of the second quantized Hamiltonian $\mathcal H$, a constraint is imposed on the first quantized matrix-valued Hamiltonian $H(k)$ at momentum $k$ as follows,

\begin{align}
\tag{5}\label{5}
\mathcal U_g \mathcal H \mathcal U_g^{-1} &= \sum_{k \alpha \beta}\mathcal U_g c^\dagger_{k \alpha} H(k)_{\alpha \beta} c_{k \beta}\mathcal U_g^{-1},\\
&= \sum_{k \alpha \beta}\mathcal U_g c^\dagger_{k \alpha}\mathcal U_g^{-1}\mathcal U_g H(k)_{\alpha \beta}\mathcal U_g^{-1}\mathcal U_g c_{k \beta}\mathcal U_g^{-1},\tag{6}&&{\text{(Inserting $\mathcal U_g \mathcal U_g^{-1} = \mathbb I$)}}\\
&= \sum_{k \alpha \beta} c^\dagger_{k_g \alpha}\mathcal U_g H(k)_{\alpha \beta}\mathcal U_g^{-1}\mathcal c_{k_g \beta},\tag{7}&&{\text{(using \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}}})\\
&= \sum_{k \alpha \beta} c^\dagger_{k \alpha}\mathcal U_g H(T_g^{-1} k)_{\alpha \beta}\mathcal U_g^{-1}\mathcal c_{k \beta},\tag{8}\label{8}&&\text{(change of variable $k_g \to k$)}
\end{align}
Eq. \eqref{8} along with \eqref{1} and \eqref{4} implies that
\begin{align}
\tag{9}
\label{9}
H(k) = \mathcal U_g H(T_g^{-1} k)\mathcal U_g^{-1}
\end{align}

---

This works out perfectly. I want to know that given a group $G$ and a representation of action of $G$ on momentum, can I construct the operators $\mathcal U_g$ (unitary representation) that defines the action of the group on the hilbert space.

I have a possible solution of this question,

- If the Hamiltonian is invariant under some symmetry $G$ then there must exist matrix $\mathcal U_g$ such that \eqref{9} will hold. Given that $\mathcal U_g$ exist, then \eqref{9} provides us with a set of equation, that needs to be solved to find the exact form of $\mathcal U_g$. Although this approach might work, it seems naive.

**Is there a better way to find $\mathcal U_g$?**

Comment: Is the different notation $U_g$ instead of $\mathcal{U}_g$ in (2) and (3) on purpose or is it a typo? It seems to me these should be the same, as they are both acting on Fock space.

Comment: @LucasBaldo Yes, that was indeed a typo. Fixed it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: You have the action of $\mathcal{U}_g$ on $c_{k\alpha}^\dagger$ and the states $\left(\prod_i c_{k_i\alpha_i}^\dagger\right)|0\rangle$ form a basis for the Fock space, so doesn't that, at least in principle, tell you everything?

Comment: Or to put it another way, why try to solve eq.(9) rather than eqs.(2) and (3)?

Comment: @BySymmetry , For me Solving (2) and (3) is more complicated as it's an action on full Fock space. Whereas, (9) is a statement on single particle Hilbert space is and is simpler to understand. When I have a non-interacting Hamiltonian, single particle basis seems to be more natural.

Comment: If all you want are the single particle states then you can more or less read of eq.(3) $\mathcal{U}_g|\mathbf{k}\alpha\rangle = \mathcal{U}_g c_{k\alpha}^\dagger|0\rangle =  \mathcal{U}_g c_{k\alpha}^\dagger  \mathcal{U}_g^{-1} \mathcal{U}_g|0\rangle = c_{k_g\alpha}^\dagger|0\rangle = |\mathbf{k}_g\alpha\rangle$

Comment: @BySymmetry That is a nice way of putting this. So one can see how the Hamiltonian changes under group action or how the states change under the same. Both are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the matrix representation of $\mathcal{U}_g$ we need first to define a basis for this operator. Since the $\mathcal{U}_g$ acts on Fock space, the basis elements will be Fock states
\begin{align}
|\mathbf{n}\rangle \equiv \prod_{\mathbf{k}, \alpha} \left(c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{k},\alpha} \right)^{n_{\mathbf{k}, \alpha}} | 0 \rangle.
\end{align}

The matrix of $\mathcal{U}_g$ elements are then
\begin{align}
\left(\mathcal{U}_g\right)_{\mathbf{n},\mathbf{n}'}
&= \langle \mathbf{n}|\mathcal{U}_g|\mathbf{n}'\rangle \\
&= \langle \mathbf{n} | \mathcal{U}_g \left[ \prod_{\mathbf{q}, \beta} \left(c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q},\beta} \right)^{n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}} \right] | 0 \rangle \\
&= \langle \mathbf{n} | \mathcal{U}_g \mathcal{U}_g^{-1} \left[ \prod_{\mathbf{q}, \beta} \mathcal{U}_g \left(c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q},\beta} \right)^{n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}} \mathcal{U}_g^{-1} \right] \mathcal{U}_g | 0 \rangle \\
&= \langle \mathbf{n} | \left[ \prod_{\mathbf{q}, \beta} \left(c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} \right)^{n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}}  \right] \mathcal{U}_g | 0 \rangle \\
&= \langle 0 | \left[ \prod_{\mathbf{k}, \alpha} \left(c_{\mathbf{k},\alpha} \right)^{n_{\mathbf{k}, \alpha}} \right] \left[ \prod_{\mathbf{q}, \beta} \left(c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} \right)^{n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}}  \right] | 0 \rangle \\
&= \langle 0 | \left[ \prod_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} \left(c_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} \right)^{n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} \left(c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} \right)^{n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}} \right] | 0 \rangle (-1)^{N} \\
&= \langle 0 | { \prod_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}  
\left[ (1-\delta_{1,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q},\beta}} \delta_{1,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}}) \left(c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} \right)^{n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}} \left(c_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} \right)^{n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}}  + \delta_{1,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q},\beta}} \delta_{1,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}}
(\delta_{\mathbf{q}_g, \mathbf{q}_g} \delta_{\beta, \beta} -c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}
c_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}\right]}) | 0 \rangle (-1)^{N} \\
&= \langle 0 | { \prod_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}  
\left[ (1-\delta_{1,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q},\beta}} \delta_{1,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}}) \left(c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} \right)^{n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}} \left(c_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} \right)^{n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} + \delta_{1,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q},\beta}} \delta_{1,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} \right]} | 0 \rangle (-1)^{N} \\
&= \langle 0 | { \prod_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}  
\left[  \delta_{0,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}}\delta_{0,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} + \delta_{1,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}}\delta_{0,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} c^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} + \delta_{0,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}}\delta_{1,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} c_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta} + \delta_{1,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q},\beta}} \delta_{1,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} \right]} | 0 \rangle (-1)^{N} \\
&= \langle 0 | { \prod_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}  
\left[  \delta_{0,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}}\delta_{0,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} + \delta_{1,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q},\beta}} \delta_{1,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} \right]} | 0 \rangle (-1)^{N} \\
&= { \prod_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}  
\left[  \delta_{0,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}}\delta_{0,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} + \delta_{1,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q},\beta}} \delta_{1,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} \right]} \langle 0  | 0 \rangle (-1)^{N} \\
&= { \prod_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}  
\left[  \delta_{0,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q}, \beta}}\delta_{0,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} + \delta_{1,n^{\prime}_{\mathbf{q},\beta}} \delta_{1,n_{\mathbf{q}_g,\beta}} \right]} (-1)^{N} \\
\end{align}